# Image Objects not loading properly based on array length

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have recently been encountering a problem that I can't seem to figure out. I have an image object I am trying to load that's based on a length of an array, so based on that number, it will instantiate a new image object, place it into an array, then finally add that array to the display list and space the elements appropriately. My code thus far:

```
    var path: String = "img/assets/blue_1.png";
    var imgLdr:Loader;
    var temp: MovieClip;

public function render(): void {
            for (var i: int = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                switch (str.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "customer":
                        switch (arr[i][i][0]) {
                            case "good":
                                temp = new MovieClip();
                                imgLdr = new Loader();
                                imgLdr.load(new URLRequest(path));
                                imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, added);
                                break;
                            case "okay":
                                //
                                //
                                break;
                            case "bad":
                                //
                                //
                                break;
                            default:
                                //
                                //
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "incdec":
                        switch (arr[i][i][1]) {
                            case true:
                                //
                                break;
                            default:
                                //
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        private function added(e: Event): void {
            objArr.push(imgLdr);
            for (var i: int = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
                addChild(objArr[i]);
                objArr[i].x = 20 * i;
            }
        }
```

As you can see I'm looping through the total length of the array and checking the individual elements contained in the multidimensional array to see if a case matches either good,okay,or bad and add the appropriate image so the final output array might end up being `[goodImg,badImg,badImg,goodImg]` for example. This process works with movie clips for example, but when I tried to load images it doesn't seem to behave and ends up loading only the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-using `imgLdr`, assigning a new reference to it each time through the loop.

By the time `added` is triggered by the loading of the first image, `imgLdr` has already been set to a newer reference in the last iteration of the loop.

Instead of pushing `imgLdr` onto your `objArr`, you should push the either the reference to the loader or the content of the `target` of the complete event:

```
private function added(e:Event): void 
{
    objArr.push(e.target.content); // this is adding the just the loaded bitmap
    //objArr.push(e.target.loader); // this would add the instance of Loader instead
    for (var i: int = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) 
    {
        addChild(objArr[i]);
        objArr[i].x = 20 * i;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, I knew it was probably something simple such as this, I will keep this in mind if I do something similar in the future. Thank you Marcela!